# jQuery Masked Input Bug

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, maskedtextbox

Ok I am using the jQuery masked input plugin version 1.2.2 from DigitalBush.

When applying masks such as:

```
$(".phone").mask("(999)-999-9999");
$(".zip").mask("99999?-9999");
```

to text boxes I am getting some strange behavior.

Basically the mask will skip every other space so for a Phone number I will get text that looks like this:

```
(_3_)-3_3-4_4_
```

Has anyone else had a similar issue??

here is a sample of the textbox html:

```
<input id="myZip" class="zip" type="text" maxlength="10"/>
```

**EDIT:**

Ok...I am having the issue with jQuery 1.4.3 and 1.4.4(tried both) and i have tested this in IE8 and FireFox.

What I noticed though is this problem only occurs when the textbox in question resides inside of a jQuery-UI modal dialog(other text boxes work fine)...I am using jQuery-UI 1.8.2 and have also tested with 1.8.7 and 1.8.8....I don't know if that will enable anyone to help me solve this or not...

here is how i have everything set up: http://jsfiddle.net/H3hTh/

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: It works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/XJZvJ/1/

Comment: I am still at a loss...even worse is that this seems to only happen intermittenly

Comment: tested this in IE8 and firefox

Comment: Works for me in Chrome, IE 8, and Firefox 3 on Windows.

Comment: Updated: this only occurs when the textbox is inside of a jQuery-UI dialog in modal mode...

Comment: I'm starting to see some issues. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/XJZvJ/3/

Comment: Here is how I have my modal set up...opens with a button, not draggable or resizeable... http://jsfiddle.net/H3hTh/

Comment: I am seeing the issue in the jsFiddle sample but not near as much as I am seeing it in my app, where it occurs 99% of the time

Comment: Just tried upgrading to jQuery-UI 1.8.8 and the behavior still exists and in fact it may even be acting more strange than before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys, I found an answer to this. I am now thinking that my problem isnt specifically related to jQuery-UI dialogs, but can happen in other cases.

The solution is to be mindful about when the mask is applied. I was applying my masks on document ready and when the "open" function was called on the dialog, something was messing up the masks.

My solution was to apply the mask on the open event of the modal dialog. Everything works great now.

In general, you just need to be careful about when the masks are applied to the text boxes to avoid interference.

Comment: hi stephen776, can u show me a sample of the code when applying the masked ?

Answer (score 0):

We found this bug while using version 1.2.2 as well, it seems to be fixed in version 1.3.